# Python, Django , Jet dashboard

Tags: python, django, dashboard, jet

I am just stepping in python with django framework. And now I want my admin dashboard with better ui with jet dashboard. I have done everything exact same as in the documentation of jet [documentation link](http://jet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install_dashboard.html). In my setting.py

```
JET_INDEX_DASHBOARD = 'dashboard.CustomIndexDashboard'
JET_APP_INDEX_DASHBOARD = 'dashboard.CustomAppIndexDashboard'
```

And in my dashboard.py

```
class CustomIndexDashboard(Dashboard):
columns = 3

def init_with_context(self, context):
    self.available_children.append(modules.LinkList)
    self.available_children.append(modules.Feed)

    self.available_children.append(google_analytics.GoogleAnalyticsVisitorsTotals)
    self.available_children.append(google_analytics.GoogleAnalyticsVisitorsChart)
    self.available_children.append(google_analytics.GoogleAnalyticsPeriodVisitors)

    site_name = get_admin_site_name(context)
    # append a link list module for "quick links"
    self.children.append(modules.LinkList(
        _('Quick links'),
        layout='inline',
        draggable=False,
        deletable=False,
        collapsible=False,
        children=[
            [_('Return to site'), '/'],
            [_('Change password'),
             reverse('%s:password_change' % site_name)],
            [_('Log out'), reverse('%s:logout' % site_name)],
        ],
        column=0,
        order=0
    ))

    # append an app list module for "Applications"
    self.children.append(modules.AppList(
        _('Applications'),
        exclude=('auth.*',),
        column=1,
        order=0
    ))

    # append an app list module for "Administration"
    self.children.append(modules.AppList(
        _('Administration'),
        models=('auth.*',),
        column=2,
        order=0
    ))

    # append a recent actions module
    self.children.append(modules.RecentActions(
        _('Recent Actions'),
        10,
        column=0,
        order=1
    ))

    # append a feed module
    self.children.append(modules.Feed(
        _('Latest Django News'),
        feed_url='http://www.djangoproject.com/rss/weblog/',
        limit=5,
        column=1,
        order=1
    ))

    # append another link list module for "support".
    self.children.append(modules.LinkList(
        _('Support'),
        children=[
            {
                'title': _('Django documentation'),
                'url': 'http://docs.djangoproject.com/',
                'external': True,
            },
            {
                'title': _('Django "django-users" mailing list'),
                'url': 'http://groups.google.com/group/django-users',
                'external': True,
            },
            {
                'title': _('Django irc channel'),
                'url': 'irc://irc.freenode.net/django',
                'external': True,
            },
        ],
        column=2,
        order=1
    ))


class CustomAppIndexDashboard(AppIndexDashboard):
def init_with_context(self, context):
    self.available_children.append(modules.LinkList)

    self.children.append(modules.ModelList(
        title=_('Application models'),
        models=self.models(),
        column=0,
        order=0
    ))
    self.children.append(modules.RecentActions(
        include_list=self.get_app_content_types(),
        column=1,
        order=0
    ))
```

And I got this error which I went through all the possible solution but either of them worked.Please help

```
return dashboard_cls(context, app_label=app_label)
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

Answer (score 1):

Your *JET_INDEX_DASHBOARD* and *JET_APP_INDEX_DASHBOARD* should point to the place where your dashboard.py file is located. So, for example if your project name is MyProject and you have put dashboard.py in the place showed below:

MyProject
|-SomeApp1
|
|-SomeApp2
|
|-MyProject
|--settings.py
|--wsgi.py
|--dashboard.py
|
|-manage.py

Then your JET_INDEX_DASHBOARD = 'MyProject.dashboard.CustomIndexDashboard'

To make things working with your value dashboard.py should be located in the project root folder.

Django JET does not include the exact explanation of that convention, but that's how it works in all Python frameworks (ex. Scrapy)

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error. It turned out that my `CustomIndexDashboard` had an `ImportError`.

Hope this helps.